# How to move CLOB data type columns from Oracle to Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery, clob

We have certain columns in our oracle application databases that are defined as CLOB and NCLOB. 
How to move CLOB data type columns from Oracle to Big Query? We are using data flow to pull the data from oracle database and write to Big Query.

Comment: According to Oracle's GitHub repo for `bdglue`, it would suggest you should map both to String: https://github.com/oracle/bdglue/blob/5fc20d9c3dcd6a228c2155f1a7795350c3767112/bdg-publishers/bigquery/src/main/java/com/oracle/bdglue/publisher/bigquery/BigQueryPublisher.java#L235

Comment: Did you read data from Oracle DB through `JdbcIO.read()` method in your initial pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to found any related information about data types equivalence in transforming Oracle DB data to GCP Bigquery sink, however I've seen in Spanner [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/migrating-oracle-to-cloud-spanner#supported_data_types) the recommended data type conversions for this kind of ETL:

**CLOB, NCLOB, LONG** columns can be converted to [STRING](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#string-type) type with some remarks:

> Small objects (less than 2,621,440 characters) can be stored as
>   **STRING**. Consider using alternative Google Cloud offerings such as
>   Cloud Storage to store larger objects.

I know the fact that GCP Spanner is a separate product and has some significant features in comparison to GCP Bigquery, but conceptually the both GCP products support simple data types, that supposedly can be used for the same interchanging **[CLOB,NCLOB] > STRING** in GCP Bigquery.

You may find `ToString()` [method](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/ToString.html) in Apache Beam SDK that can approach above mentioned conversion, adjusting it in the particular `PCollection` inside your pipeline code.

Read more in this [article](https://www.progress.com/tutorials/cloud-and-hybrid/etl-on-premises-oracle-data-to-google-bigquery-using-google-cloud-dataflow).